# Unset php variables before form submit (post) using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, unset

I have two variables `$get_book_id` and `$_GET['book_id']` and a form to post some other data. When the submit button is clicked I want to empty the above two variables and to post the remaining values using form post.

The jquery code looks like this.

*index.php*

```
    $('#submit_button').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'empty_variable.php',
                success: function(data) { 
                },
                error: function(ts) { alert(ts.responseText) }
            });
    });

    <form action="process.php" method="post">

            .................

    </form>
```

empty_variable.php

```
    <?php
    $get_book_id = '';
    $_GET['book_id'] = '';
    ?>
```

process.php

```
<?php 
echo $_GET['book_id'];
echo $get_book_id;
print_r($_POST);    
?>
```

What I want to do is, empty two variables using jQuery on form submit. How can I do that ?
In the process page I still see the `$_GET` values and `$get_book_id`.

Please don't ask me to empty the value in index.php page.

**Unset php variables before form submit (post) using jQuery**

Thanks

Kimz

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer, use a post request and set the variable to blank if the field is blank:

Change submit input to a button like this:
index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#submit_button').on('click', function(e) {
              $('#book_id').val('');
              $(this).submit();                     
         });
    });                       
</script>
<form id="form_id" action="process.php" method="POST">
    <input id="book_id" name="book_id" type="text" />
    <button id="submit_button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

process.php

```
if($_POST['book_id'] = '') $get_book_id = $_POST['book_id'];
echo $_POST['book_id'];
echo $get_book_id;
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: instead of name if i want to pass the id how should i do?
$('input[id="book_id"]').val('');
?? Is this correct?

Comment: i'm getting an error after using ur code as "too much recursion"
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 $('#submit_button').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data:{"clearBit":"YES"},  //use the data to refresh the specified variables on process.php page
            url: 'empty_variable.php',
            success: function(data) { 
            },
            error: function(ts) { alert(ts.responseText) }
        });
});
```

**Process.php:**

```
 <?php
   if(isset($_POST['clearBit']) && $_POST['clearBit']=='YES')
   {
     $get_book_id = '';
     $_GET['book_id'] = '';
   }    
?>
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Not working, As i said I need to empty/unset it using jquery ajax and not using the traditional post method. any idea?

Comment: From your client script there is no way you can control server script variables.btw, what you mean by not working ? above code is failing to reset the variables ?

Comment: hello bro, i have asked a question again in SOF
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954809/empty-variables-before-post-using-jquery-only