# Empty variables before post using jQuery ONLY

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have checked this question in SOF, 
[How to prevent form element from sending some fields we don't want?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223365/how-to-prevent-form-element-from-sending-some-fields-we-dont-want)

Here is my code

index.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(formElement).submit(function() {
        ... how to do the jquery stuff.. 
        return true;
    });

    <?php
    $my_variable_with_value1 = 'abc';
    $my_variable_with_value2 = 'def';
    $another_one_variable = 'mango';
     ?>
    <form method="post" action="process.php">
    <input type="text" id="id1" name="name1" value="<?php echo $my_variable_with_value1 ?>"  />
    <input type="text" id="id2" name="name2" value="<?php echo $my_variable_with_value2 ?>"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

I need to do the following
1. Before the page is submitted i need to unset/empty the variable values using JQUERY ONLY
2. I have to show the variable in index.php and not in the next page process.php

In other words, HOW CAN I EMPTY THE VARIABLES $my_variable_with_value1 AND $another_one_variable BEFORE PAGE SUBMIT USING JQUERY

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: You are not using $another_one_variable in the form. Then why u want to unset it?

Comment: so your dont want to pass the text fields with id `id1` & `id2` right ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly submitting the form using

```
$(formElement).submit(function() {
```

call an `onclick` function in button as:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitform()" />
```

and in the js function you can set the value of input fields to empty like:

```
function submitform()
{
    $('#id1').val('');
    $('form').submit();
}
```

Comment: thansk bro, one more query - if i have a variable $var='aaa' and if i want to empty that also using jQuery how an i do that

Comment: You can do it in any other way if you explain the context in which the resetting of php variable is required..

Answer (score 0):

Using below code you can set value of var1 (ID) and var2 (ID) to blank.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(formElement).submit(function() {
        $("#Var1").val("");
        $("#Var2").val("");
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: thansk bro, one more query - if i have a variable $var='aaa' and if i want to empty that also using jQuery how an i do that

Comment: Hold on, what is #var1 & 2? You probably mean `id`s. @user3350885 PHP and jQuery variables are different, don't mix them up.

Comment: $var you mean in php?

Comment: $var will be any php variable of my choice. this is for my info - just give me a snippet to unset any php variable before form submit using JQUERY

Comment: @user3350885 You will have to save the PHP variable value into a jQuery variable and then based on your conditions, _unset the jQuery variable_ where necessary.